# Replacing static background image with simple j Query slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm busy building a website and have a banner in it. The banner consists out of a static background image with static text overlay.
Now I want to keep the banner with the text overlay, but replace the static background image with a simple slideshow. The images should be replaced every 3 seconds. It should be a continuous loop, triggered on page load event. This function should utilize jQuery.

This is the html code for the banner as it is at the moment:

```
<!--BANNER HTML-->
<div class="banner">
  <div class="banner-text">
    <h1>LONG LAYOVER?</h1>
    <h1>Is Amsterdam Schiphol your transfer hub?</h1>
    <h4>Make the most of your layover by doing some sightseeing!<br>Tailored according to the length of your layover</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.banner h1, .banner h1, .banner h4 {
  margin: 0;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.banner {
  color: white;
  background: url(images/bannerimage.png) top left/cover no-repeat;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Does anybody have a smart solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpliest answer comes to my mind is defining functions and call them in timeout functions as shown in the [**DEMO here**](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=b2929c75aef2e675f2ce4cfd72ceb3c0)
You can also use togglaClass instead of .css() function. I would prefer toggleClass but just did this was is quicker for me.

Comment: Thank you Güney, it seems to be a good solution. I've implemented the code, and the background image was changed, but the slideshow doesn't start. I guess I have to 'call' the js in the html file, right?

Comment: Do you have jquery added to your metas? if yes then yes add the code inside to the <script> tag and put it into the head of the page.

Comment: Hi Güney, this is my first time utilizing jQuery, so I don't know exactly what jQuery code to add where. Where will my metas be?

Comment: go to this link; http://jquery.com/download/ and download jquery compressed 3.2.1 and put it into your document root. then put this code into your head tag '<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>'. P.S: Make sure that src attribute is targeting the location of the jquery you donwloaded and put document root. I mean if you put it in a folder they src="foldername/jquery-.3.2.1.min.js"